# CMake CEGUI / GTK2 Configuration Error

Tags: c++, cmake, ogre, cegui

I am trying to build and use CEGUI (Crazy Eddie's GUI) as a library for Ogre. I am using CMake, but during the configuring step for the dependencies, I got the following error:

> Some or all of the gtk libraries were not found. (missing:  GTK2_GTK_LIBRARY GTK2_GTK_INCLUDE_DIR GTK2_GDK_INCLUDE_DIR GTK2_GDKCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR GTK2_GDK_LIBRARY GTK2_GLIB_INCLUDE_DIR GTK2_GLIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR GTK2_GLIB_LIBRARY) 
>   CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
>   Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
>   Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
>      used as include directory in directory C:/Cegui/cegui-0.8.3/cegui/src/RendererModules/Ogre

CEGUI 0.8.3
cegui-deps-0.8.x-src.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have GTK2 installed on your machine (as far as I can tell, it is not part of the CEGUI dependency download archive).
2. Ensure that CMake can find the library and all it needs. From having a look at the official [CMake FindGKT2 script](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGTK2.cmake#L266) (and I couldn't find a custom one for CEGUI, so the official one is most likely used), the following locations are checked:

   - /usr/local/lib64
   - /usr/local/lib
   - /usr/lib64
   - /usr/lib
   - /opt/gnome/include [and /lib]
   - /opt/openwin/include [and /lib]
   - /sw/include [and /lib]
   - /opt/local/include [and /lib]
   - /usr/pkg/lib
   - /usr/pkg/include/glib
   - $ENV{GTKMM_BASEPATH}/include [and /lib]
   - [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\gtkmm\2.4;Path]/include
   - [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\gtkmm\2.4;Path]/lib
   - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\gtkmm\2.4;Path]/include
   - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\gtkmm\2.4;Path]/lib

So if you are on windows, setting the environment variable `GTKMM_BASEPATH` will probably be the easiest way. Alternatively, you can also directly enter the paths to your GTK2 installation in the advanced CEGUI view.